# Generating ER diagram and export to some interactive map

Tags: mysql, generator, interactive, erd

I am looking for a tool which would generate ER diagram from an existing MySQL database and could be exported to some interactive map (HTML, Flash, etc).

I want to get out the effect, that when you select a table it highlights all the connections.

MySQL Workbench already does this, but can not be exported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The good folks at google have created something similar. It's not exactly what you're looking for but maybe you can hack it to suit your needs?

http://code.google.com/p/database-diagram/